# Remote Desktop Services: Fixed hostname per client

Tags: remote-desktop, rds

I'm investigating the deployment of a [RDS-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services) solution and I wondered if an RDS session can be assigned a unique hostname based on the PC the session originated from.

I need this to allow the following scenario to work:

- A Client application is started in RDS
- This application opens a web-application
- This web-application takes the IP-address of the request to resolve the Hostname of the computer where the request originated.
- That hostname is then used to load computer-specific settings for the  web-application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we ripped all pc-specific settings from the web-app. Since there was no reliable way to determine the host (even in non-rds environments), it didn't make sense anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I have logging enabled on the Remote Desktop Gateway server and put the log files in a share. You can choose from different log formats and browse them for user's IP or the user-hostname.

A similar question can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/684318/get-rd-user-client-hostname-in-server-2012-r2-rd-deployment)!